# How should I represent a (one (many A to many B) to many C) relationship in SQL

Tags: sql

Using the following notation:

- `A >< B` - Many  A and B
- `A <= B` - One A to many B

I would like to represent `(A >< B) <= C`, i.e associating many Cs with every link between A and B.

Here're some ideas I've had (warning: pseudocode)

1. **primary key pairs, duplicated**

   ```
   table ABMap
       primary foreign A_id
       primary foreign B_id

   table C
       primary C_id
       foreign A_id
       foreign B_id
       # more data
   ```
2. **unique constraint on mapping**

   ```
   table ABMap
       primary AB_id
       foreign A_id
       foreign B_id
       unique (A_id, B_id)

   table C
       primary C_id
       foreign AB_id
       # more data
   ```
3. **unique constraint on mapping id**

   ```
   table ABMap
       auto_increment AB_id
       primary foreign A_id
       primary foreign B_id
       unique (AB_id)

   table C
       primary C_id
       foreign AB_id
   ```

Which should I use, and why?

Comment: Does each C only belong to a single AB combo?  All your designs make it so because C_id is the PK in your C.  If a single C can only belong to one AB combo, then all your designs could be used; if not, then you need and AB_C_map table as well, with corresponding revisions to the C table.

Comment: There is exactly one AB combo for every C (but multiple Cs for every AB combo)

Comment: I assume that (null, B) and (A, null) are not possible combinations for ABMap?

Comment: @simo.379209: Correct. Good point

Answer (score 1):

I like #2 the best.

```
table ABMap
    primary AB_id
    foreign A_id
    foreign B_id
    unique (A_id, B_id)
    clustered_index (A_id, B_id)   --- Add
    index (A_id)                   --- Add if B not supplied sometimes
    index (B_id)                   --- Add if A not supplied sometimes

table C
    primary C_id
    foreign AB_id
    # more data
```

Using the primary key of AB_id will provide a fast lookup when joining table C.

However if most queries are going to be searching using both of the parents then clustered indexing the data using the (A_id, B_id), will perform fastest.  If *some* queries are going to provide just A or just B, then separate indexes on these two fields will support those queries.